# Prove that a rectangle can't filled with these tetrominos

Tags: contest-math, combinatorial-geometry, tiling

We have a $m*n$ rectangle prove that it can't filled with these tetrominos.

tetrominos used:$L$_tetromino-straight tetromino-$T$_tetromino-square tetromino-skew tetromino.

**My attempt**:Because all of our shapes that we want to fill with are tetrominos then our rectangle can't filled if $m*n$ is not a multiply of $4$.After that I tried different kinds of coloring to show it can't be filled the resault can easily proved if we should use every kind of tetrominos but it is impossible for me to prove it can't filled if we can use just $1$ kind or so tetrominos.Please suggest me a kind of coloring that I can prove this.Thanks.

Comment: A $2\times 2$ rectangle can certainly be filled by the square tetromino, and a $1\times 4$ rectangle by the straight tetromino, so it seems the claim is false

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yeah,I found it in the book strategies of problem solving.(Artur angle).

Comment: You mean [Arthur Engel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Engel_(mathematician)), not "Artur angle".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes I mean him.